# How to check for an intermediate page while Automating in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

There is an option to turn the intermediate page ON/OFF.
How to navigate to the page if the page is present. If not present how to continue the code.

Comment: Did you try out anything by now? What is your exact usecase?

Comment: I tried to put the intermediate page's url in if case, the code runs to click on the page, but I am not able to continue to run the remaining code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.arg("...."))

if (element.isDisplayed())
{
   driver.findElement(By.arg("....")).click();
 }
```